# Typescript fails when a condition is moved over to another function

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to clean up some code and ran into a problem with Typescript.

Here is what I have:

```
type TSource = {
    someProperty: string;
} | string;

const handler = ({ source }: { source: TSource }): string =>
    typeof source === 'string' || typeof source === 'number' 
        ? source
        : source.someProperty;
```

This works just fine, but I'm trying to make this code a bit cleaner like so:

```
const isPrimitive = ({ element }: { element: any }) =>
    ['string', 'number', 'boolean']
        .includes(typeof element);

type TSource = {
    someProperty: string;
} | string;

const handler = ({ source }: { source: TSource }): string =>
    isPrimitive({ element: source })
        ? source
        : source.someProperty;
//               ^^^^^^^^^^^^ error here
```

I've tried the following:

```
const handler = ({ source }: { source: TSource }): string =>
    isPrimitive({ element: source })
        ? source
        : (source.someProperty as Omit<TSource, 'string'>);
```

But this didn't work. What can I do here?

Comment: See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html - a vanilla boolean isn't sufficient, you need a _type predicate_

Answer (score 0):

See [Using type predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates)

```ts
const isPrimitive = (x: any): x is string | number | boolean =>
    ['string', 'number', 'boolean'].includes(typeof x);

type TSource = {
    someProperty: string;
} | string;

const handler = ({ source }: { source: TSource }): string =>
    isPrimitive(source)
        ? source
        : source.someProperty;
```